# Two Component's Top overlay above Rule

Tags: altium

As you see in the attached picture. Two component's top overlay is above 
in my pcb design; I saw a error, but Altium Rule check does not inform me.
I need a rule for this error. Can you help me?

[image: Need Rule]

Comment: Are you sure it's actually an overlay? The line thickness probably isn't part of the DRC computation.

Comment: I am pretty sure layers rule is work clearly. This picture is a sample. I want to see components above error. But I do not know which rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a rule using the Top Overlay as an outline. If you want to have the clearance between two components checked, create 3D models and a component clearance rule.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have 3D Models. Now İt is work . so There is no problem with components' top overlays